# Inserting rows in ListView without moving the screen in Android

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I got a ListView displaying everything that is in specific category and a service that is pulling data from a web server. I am presenting a lot of data and if I pull the data anew, feed it to the adapter and notify of the data change the whole listview gets refreshed. On one side there is no issue with that, but I wish the user to maintain the same position he has left on the screen.

Is it possible to keep the same offset or insert just 1 row in a table without moving the screen to the top of the list?

Comment: How do you refresh the listview?

Answer (score 0):

You need to maintain two variables one for current selected index and second for the top position of selected item from top of the list View.

```
int listSelectedIndex,top;
```

Use following method to save the current list position. You should call this method before notifying the data change.

```
private void saveListPosition() {

        listSelectedIndex = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
        View v = lstQuoteProducts.getChildAt(0);
        top = (v == null) ? 0 : v.getTop();
    }
```

After notify data change call following method to reset the saved position of list.

```
listView.setSelectionFromTop(listSelectedIndex, top);
```